# Represent Matrix in tabular form C++

Tags: c++, matrix, tabular-form

Currently, I am trying to use the linked node to represent the matrix. My codes are working fine, while I not sure it is possible to represent my matrix in tabular form instead of **(x,y) = value**.

While my printout() method only print it out when temp != NULL, and this is the result

```
Element position(3,3) = 9
```

I want to represent it like

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

Below is my codes with the linked node in the matrix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


typedef struct node
{
    int column;
    int value;
    int row;
    struct node *next;
} element;


void Init(element *x[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        x[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void Insert(element *x[], int row, int column, int value)
{
    int r = row;
    element *p;

    element *news = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
    news->row = row;
    news->column = column;
    news->value = value;

    if (x[r] == NULL)
    {
        x[r] = news;
        news->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p = x[r];
        if (news->column < p->column)
        {
            news->next = p;
            x[r] = news;
        }
        else if (news->column > p->column)
        {
            while (p->next != NULL && p->next->column < news->column)
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
            news->next = p->next;
            p->next = news;
        }
        else cout << "An element already exists there!!\n";
    }
}


void Printout(element *x[])
{
    int i, test = 0;
    element *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        temp = x[i];
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << "Element position" << "(" << i << "," << temp->column << ") = " << temp->value << endl;
            test = 1;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

    }

    if (test == 0) {
        cout << "This matrix is empty" << endl;
    }
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int choice, column, row, value, number;
    element *a[10], *b[10], *sum[10];
    Init(a);    Init(b);    Init(sum);
    do
    {
        cout << "Add Sparse Matrix" << endl;
        cout << "1. Insert in A" << endl;
        cout << "2. Insert in B" << endl;
        cout << "3. Print 2 matrix" << endl;
        cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your option" << endl;

        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            do
            {
                cout << "Enter row -> ";
                cin >> row;
            } while (row < 0 || row > 11);

            do
            {
                cout << "Enter column -> ";
                cin >> column;
            } while (column < 0);

            cout << "Enter value -> ";
            cin >> value;

            Insert(a, row, column, value);

            break;
        case 2:
            do
            {
                cout << "Enter row -> ";
                cin >> row;
            } while (row < 0 || row > 11);

            do
            {
                cout << "Enter column -> ";
                cin >> column;
            } while (column < 0);

            cout << "Enter value -> ";
            cin >> value;

            Insert(b, row, column, value);

            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\n::::::: MATRIX A :> \n\n";
            Printout(a);
            cout << "\n::::::: MATRIX B :> \n\n";
            Printout(b);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "WRONG CHOICE\n\n";
        }
    } while (choice != 0);




    return 0;


}
```

Sorry for asking this question, I am just started to learn C++ programming, need someone to enlighten me. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Hi Roger, welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm afraid it isn't immediately obvious what you are asking for.  Since your code is working fine what is it that you want to change?   Also the terms  _tabular form_ and _(x,y) = value_ may be ambiguous.  I'm sure they mean something specific to you but your readers may not interpret them the same way as you.  Finally, the `cout` in your `main` mentions **sparse matrix**.  If your intention is to minimise memory use by only storing non-zero values it would help your readers if you mentioned that explicitly.  There are helpful tips in: [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your linked list is used to saves the memory usage, you can write some codes to print the zero until the width is reached.

```
void SM::Printout(element *x[])
{
    int width = -1;
    for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++)
    {
        for (element *node = x[row]; node != NULL; node = node->next)
            if (node->column > width)
                width = node->column;
    }
    width++;

    for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++)
    {
        int col = 0;
        for (element *node = x[row]; node != NULL; node = node->next)
        {
            for (; col < node->column; col++)
                cout << "0  ";
            if (node->value != NULL)
            cout << node->value << "  ";
            col = node->column + 1;
        }
        for (; col < width; col++)
            cout << "0  ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want, thank you for replying my post. Regards.